# How to send WAP SI Messages with JSMPP

Tags: java, sms, smpp, jsmpp

I want to send wap-push message over smpp, using jsmpp library. I found some material, but it is not working. Can someone explain me, what is the technology for sending wap-push message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the jsmpp, you need to set esmclass to 64 and datacoding to 245.

Comment: @Jasonw, I do it, but I don't know where can I write text & hyperlink? I know the right PDU format. In JSMPP how can I send this PDU?

Comment: if you have the right PDU, then the text and url is *within* the pdu, and the method submitShortMessage should be able to send this pdu.

Comment: @Jasonw, sorry I don't clearly understand you. Example, 

[code]
String pdu = "060504{ans so}";

session.submitShortMessage("CMT",TypeOfNumber.INTERNATIONAL, NumberingPlanIndicator.UNKNOWN,"1111", TypeOfNumber.INTERNATIONAL,
NumberingPlanIndicator.UNKNOWN, "+994111111111", new ESMClass(64),
(byte) 0, (byte) 1, timeFormatter.format(new Date()), null,
registeredDelivery, (byte) 0, new GeneralDataCoding(245),
(byte) 0, pdu);
[/code]

Is it correct?

Comment: No.
a) your example pdu is incorrect.
b) the hex string pdu need to be converted to byte[]. there is a HexUtil class and method convertHexStringToBytes. You can use this and convert the hex string to byte.

Comment: String messageId = session.submitShortMessage("CMT", TypeOfNumber.INTERNATIONAL, NumberingPlanIndicator.UNKNOWN, "55662", TypeOfNumber.ALPHANUMERIC, NumberingPlanIndicator.UNKNOWN, "your_phone_number", new ESMClass(64), (byte)0, (byte)1,  timeFormatter.format(new Date()), null, new RegisteredDelivery(SMSCDeliveryReceipt.DEFAULT), (byte)0, new GeneralDataCoding(245), (byte)0, HexUtil.convertHexStringToBytes("0605040B8423F025060803AE81EAAF82B48401056A0045C60D036578616D706C652E636F6D0007010377656C636F6D6520746F207761702073697465000101"));

Comment: I have got a error like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68473714/jsmpp-negative-response-00000001-message-length-is-invalid-found, any ideas? please

Answer (score 0):

There is no valid constructor for GeneralDataCoding(245) so I added a piece of code to GenrealDataCodin.java to resolve it.

```
public GeneralDataCoding(int i) {
    this.directvalue = (byte)i;
    directValueFlag = true;

    this.alphabet = Alphabet.ALPHA_DEFAULT;
    this.messageClass = MessageClass.CLASS0;
    this.compressed = true;
}

public byte toByte() {
    if(directValueFlag == true){
        value = directvalue;
    }
    else{
        byte value = compressed ? DataCodingFactory00xx.MASK_COMPRESSED : 0;
        value |= alphabet.value();
        if (messageClass != null) {
            value |= DataCodingFactory00xx.MASK_CONTAIN_MESSAGE_CLASS;
            value |= messageClass.value();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is there another way to set  datacoding to 245, it is because I think you have recompiled from source to add this contructor, so

Comment: public byte toByte() {
    if(directValueFlag == true){
        value = directvalue;
    }
    else{
        byte value = compressed ? DataCodingFactory00xx.MASK_COMPRESSED : 0;
        value |= alphabet.value();
        if (messageClass != null) {
            value |= DataCodings.MASK_CONTAIN_MESSAGE_CLASS;
            value |= messageClass.value();
        }
      return value;
} Really works?